# Is It Wrong To Create More Than One Collection For Every New Object in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, collections, nosql

I'm building an app that's intended to be like an intermediate between an educational organization and a profitable organization so that the app can register new schools, universities ..etc and then create a new collection for every new school, university .. I create. But I was reading some posts here on **stackoverflow** and some people were saying that it's wrong to create a new collection on a post request. But the thing is every school has different students, teachers, staff members ...etc and it seems illogical to store all the students of different schools in **one embedded document**. So what **should** I do?

Comment: Yes.  Collections are synonymous with tables in a RDBMS system.  It would be unwise to have a table in an RDBMS system for each record.  Index maintenance would be a nightmare.  Also if you want to sort or aggregate similar data it is very difficult if the documents are all stored in different collections.  Instead create one collection and in this collection insert many documents - one for each school in your example, and embed the relational data.

Comment: It is one of the benefits in MongoDB (or many other NoSQL databases) that it does not require all documents need to be the same structure. Put all in one collection only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, correct creating a collection of each and every school is problematic but using some database design/data modelling techniques can help you here

As Schools can be considered as an institute, so we can have one collection of institutes, where each institute will have its own unique Id

```
Institutes

{
  _id: "<Institute id>",
  name: "<school name>",
  desc: "<desc>"
  ...others
}
```

Then we can create one collection for the User, which contains all the user's information like name, contact info etc.

```
Users

{
  _id: "<user id>"
  name: "<user name>"
  ...others
}
```

Then we can create one collection which show which user is associated with which institute and having what role

```
User_Associated_Institute

{
  _id: {
    school_id: <Institute id>,
    user_id: <user id>
  },
  role: <Staff/Teacher/Student>,
  ...other
}
```

Then finally we can have a collection of which institute is offering what all courses ​

```
Courses_Offered_Institute

{
  _id: "<course id>",
  name: "<course name>",
  desc: "<desc>",
  institutes: ["<Institute id>"],
  ....others
}
```

This is just a suggestion, where you can modify the design as per your use cases